# Does an Adamantine greatclub always deal critical damage like other Adamantine weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, special-materials, storm-kings-thunder

In general adamantine weapons always deal critical damage on a hit:

> Whenever an adamantine weapon or piece of ammunition hits an object, the hit is a critical hit.

*- Xanathar's Guide to Everything, page 78.*

However, in SKT chapter 6 room 14 (page 154) it says:

> She wields an adamantine greatclub. This magic
>   weapon has no bonus to attack or damage rolls.

Does this mean it also does **not** crit? Or does it still crit like adamantine weapons do in general, but simply has no +n to attack or damage roll?

Also: is this a property of this particular weapon in this adventure? Or is it a property that always applies to adamantine greatclubs?

Outside of D&D lore this would make sense because adamantine is a very light material but is still very strong and can be sharpened. This makes is a great material for piercing and slashing weapons (swords, axes, arrows), but a terrible material for bludgeoning damage. 
However, I don't know if this applies in D&D lore as well (I haven't read it anywhere up untill now).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, a clarification. As noted in the comments

## XGTE Adamantine Weapons Always Crit on Objects

> Whenever an adamantine weapon or piece of ammunition hits an **object**, the hit is a critical hit.

Just so we're clear...Adamantine weapons only auto-crit when they hit Objects, not all the time. So they don't "always crit," they "always crit when they hit an Object."

For this greatclub in particular...

## It's Complicated

We have a bit of an A before B problem here that complicates things.

The rules for Adamantine Weapons were released in Xanathar's Guide to Everything, which was published in November 2017. Storm King's Thunder was released in September of 2016.

So...in short, the Adamantine Weapon listed in SKT was released before there were rules for Adamantine Weapons that dictated that they always critted on Objects.

So if we look at the Adamantine Greatclub from the perspective of 2016...then it does precisely what the book says--it's a magical weapon (for the purposes of resistance/immunity), is made of Adamantine, but has no other special properties. If we look at it from the perspective of today, then logically it would have the 'crits on objects' property.

So in this case, given the context of the rules we now have, it *should* always land critical hits on objects. However, when Storm King's Thunder was first released, it did not--and if your DM does not have or is not using Xanathar's Guide to Everything for the added context of how Adamantine Weapons work according to that rulebook, then it may not at your table.

Comment: So I would like to point out a few things. First, the "no bonuses to attack or damage rolls" likely is specifically referring to it not being a +1 or better weapon. Second, adamantine weapons already had the property of "always counting as magical" for damage purposes, so *XGTE* expanded their rules. Third, (and probably less importantly) *XGTE* came out only a year after *SKT*, and due to development cycles, the rules for adamantine weapons in *XGTE* were probably already around in some form when *SKT* came out.

Comment: @RevenantBacon However, my point still stands. When SKT was released, even if the rules for Adamantine Weapons existed within WotC's brains, they were not released and therefore did not apply to that adventure at the time. So, at the time SKT was released, Adamantine Weapons did not autocrit objects because, even if those rules existed internally to WotC...they were not published as part of SKT. It was a "Magic Weapon" with "No bonuses to attack/damage." So, by SKT alone, you get the Magic Damage resistance/immunity bypass, but nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. I just thought it would be worth mentioning those things.

Comment: I would note that the answer to "does it always crit" is not really complicated; the answer is "no" regardless. Whether it always crits against objects in particular might be a little more complicated. OP noted in a comment (replying to yours) on the question that this was the source of their confusion, so I'd suggest stating that front and center in your header.

Comment: I don't understand why you end with "it probably does critical damage on objects". I see a strong argument for (the rules say so), but you don't present any argument against it. Maybe I'm missing the point here, but it seems like you are implying that rules that come out after content, don't apply to that content? If so, it would be good to outright state that. It's unsatisfying to read through an answer that isn't exactly clear to end up with a non-comital conclusion.

Comment: @gszavae The point is simply that it's unclear. If your DM does not own XGTE, but only SKT, there's no reason for them to know about the rule of how Adamantine weapons behave in XGTE...since all they have to go off of is SKT.

Comment: @guildsbounty I think your conclusion, as it is written, weakens your post. You say it "probably does critical damage to objects, but did not when the adventure was first published" I think something like "it does critical damage to objects, but not when the adventure was first published" or "but your DM may not be using the XGTE sourcebook" or something like that. The "probably" is a bit nebulous.

Comment: @gszavae That's a good point, revised that last line a bit.

Comment: @guilds I know many rules of *Xanathar's* are optional, are the ones on adamantine weapons optional as well?

Comment: @Medix2 They are not specifically cited as optional...but if your DM does not want to juggle yet-another-source-book (or does not *own* that sourcebook), that's their decision.

Answer (score 12):

Let's break this down.

First, an adamantine weapon doesn't *always* deal critical damage on a hit. Note the wording of adamantine weapons:

> Whenever an adamantine weapon or piece of ammunition **hits an object,** the hit is a critical hit.

Adamantine weapons only deal critical hit damage if they hit an **object**, not a creature.

Second, what is a critical hit?

A critical hit is a roll of a 20 on a 20-sided die, regardless of any modifiers (PHB, pg.194).

Furthermore:

> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll extra dice for the attack's damage against the target.

<sup>PHB, pg.196</sup>

Therefore, Kayalithica's adamantine greatclub still crits on objects like a normal adamantine weapon since a critical hit happens irrelevant of any modifiers.